# Winforms best practice for Adding/Editing forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I studying developing under .NET C# WINFORMS

I have form of adding teacher to DB.

Now I need to make form for editing an teacher.

It's normal to create different form for this purpose? Because it have the same controls, so maybe just call the same form of adding teacher, but load data to controls, and change button from ADD to SAVE?

In web developement (php) I simetimes use the same form for editing/adding data, because it's not too hard to handle this behavior. But I am not sure that this practice is good form windows programming too.

Here the form of adding. I am afraid that it will be hard to maintenance this code later, if I reuse this form for editing too.

Tnx.

[image: This form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

imo yeah you should reuse the same form... less code to maintaint in long term

edit : as imp0ssible said this isn't possible if it's the main form

just make 2 constructor so you know if you are adding or editing a teacher

Answer (score 2):

Is this form, the main form?
If no, you can call different constructors for (add, edit,...) of this form

Comment: I just added form example. This isn't main form. I call it only for adding teacher. And I want be able o edit later teachers by loading data from DB by id.

Comment: new TeacherForm().Show() is for adding and new TeacherForm(Teacher teacher).Show() for editing. Something like...

Answer (score 1):

I would typically approach this by using the same form. For clarity, I would not relabel the buttons, but rather use a different caption and/or other clear headline indicating whether the user is adding or updating.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Reproduktor rep;
    public Edit(Reproduktor rep)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.rep = rep;
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(rep.typSoustavy);
        if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex == 0)
        {
            txtFl.Text = (rep as Reproduktor).fl.ToString(); //+fr
        }
        else if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex ==1)
        {
            txtSub.text blablabla 
        }
        else if(comboBox1 ==2)
        { }
        textBox1.Text = rep.vyrobce;
        textBox2.Text = rep.nazev;
        //cena.tostring
        comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindStringExact(rep.bluethoot);
    }

    private void buttonStorno_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        this.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Great answer. Even I missed `InitializeComponent();` , then I add it, and it work. You save my day.

Answer (score 0):

Another constructor could work, in that way you could know which controls to enable or disabled depending on your needs, that's the easiest way and you will reuse the same form/code.